# PayPal IPN Processing

Tags: paypal, vbscript, paypal-ipn

I have implemented an IPN listener in VBScript/Classic ASP.
From my side, it seems to work perfectly.
When it is called, it sends the message back to Paypal appending `cmd=_notify-validate`. It then checks the response for `objHttp.status = 200` and `objHttp.responseText = "VERIFIED"` then adds the order to my database.

However Paypal are sending me emails;

> Subject: PayPal Instant Payment Notification Warning
>
> Instant Payment Notifications sent to the following URL(s) are failing:

Comment: Does PayPal expect a specific response from your page perhaps that you are not sending back as an acknowledgement the response has been processed?

Comment: @Lankymart    Having investigated further, it seems there is a discrepancy between what some of the Paypal documentation says needs to be done 
(After receiving the IPN message from PayPal, your listener returns an empty HTTP 200 response to PayPal. Otherwise, PayPal resends the IPN message.)

and the code samples Paypal give, in which this step isn't performed.

Is this step required?
And if so, can anyone give me a code example in VBScript/Classic ASP showing how to do it?

Comment: Is this the code sample you are using? - [paypal/ipn-code-samples](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/asp/paypal_ipn.asp)

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/) it does look like you are missing step 2 - *"After receiving the IPN message from PayPal, your listener returns an empty HTTP 200 response to PayPal. Otherwise, PayPal resends the IPN message."*.

Comment: @Lankymart Yes, that is exactly the code sample which I used.

Comment: Anthony, how did you get on in the end?

Comment: Hi, after contacting PayPal, it appears that the problem is not with my code, but an error at their end!
"Currently, the internal team is checking on what is causing this. We will provide you an update once they have updated us.
We do apologize for the inconvenience caused."

Answer (score 0):

According to [IPN Testing](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNTesting/)

> Every listener must include code that handles the "error notification" IPN messages.

Either way you should follow the steps in the [IPN troubleshooting tips](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNTesting/#id091GFE00WY4) step by step.

Here is a few I've picked out that should help.

- Check the URLs listed in your IPN history to ensure that PayPal is posting each IPN to your listener.
- Check your web server's access and error logs.
- Check your programming language's error log.
- Verify that your IPN listener is responding to all messages, even those you do not intend to process.

---

Further to the [OPs comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866253/paypal-ipn-processing/40867550#comment68950297_40866253)

> *the code samples Paypal give, in which this step isn't performed. Is this step required?*

it sounds like you are missing Step 2 from the workflow in the documentation

> *2. After receiving the IPN message from PayPal, your listener returns an empty HTTP 200 response to PayPal. Otherwise, PayPal resends the IPN message.*

Judging by the PHP sample as well both seem to send the verification first, which doesn't tally with the workflow suggested by the documentation.

In which case you should just be able to do

```vb
Response.Status = "200 OK"
```

after the rest of the code, make sure nothing else is written back using `Response.Write()` so the server response is blank, you could even use

```vb
Call Response.Clear()
```

before setting the `Response.Status` to make sure nothing else has been written from the `Response` buffer. This will only work however if `Response.Buffer` has been set to `True` beforehand *(usually at the beginning of the script)*.

Comment: I tried adding the `Response.Status = "200 OK"` but it still doesn't work (as far as PayPal are concerned)

Comment: How would I send a status of 200 using just objHttp.Send, so that I can send the response earlier as per documentation ?

Comment: The thing is @AntonyMeadley, sending a "response" is not the same as sending a "request", when you use `objHttp.Send` it's making a new "request" to PayPal and it's PayPal who will send a "response". What do you see in the IPN History in PayPal, is the listener returning `200 OK` there?

Comment: To be honest you shouldn't need to specify `Response.Status` as once the script finishes it should default to `200 OK` by default as long as no `500 Internal Server` errors occur, that's why I'd check the IPN History first to make sure PayPal is receiving the expected response code.

Comment: Looking at the IPN History, it appears that the HTTP response code is 500, even though I have used your code above to set the Status to "200 OK"

Comment: @AntonyMeadley which means the page is generating an error response, you need to debug the listener page, this is why PayPal believes the process is failing.

Comment: @AntonyMeadley If you have have copied [the sample](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/master/asp/paypal_ipn.asp) like for like then the first line should trigger an error `' ASP .NET/VBScript (requires MSXML)` it's a VBScript comment but it's not inside the ASP pre-processor tags `<% %>`, if it's there I'd recommend removing it as it's not required.